# plotly r choropleth with subplot not working as desired

Tags: r, maps, plotly, choropleth

I am using the example provided and expanding it to produce two subplots of choropleth as follows. I only get one plot and with strange taller scale:

```
library(plotly)
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv")
df$hover <- with(df, paste(state, '<br>', "Beef", beef, "Dairy", dairy, "<br>", "Fruits", total.fruits, "Veggies", total.veggies,
"<br>", "Wheat", wheat, "Corn", corn))

# give state boundaries a white border
l <- list(color = toRGB("white"), width = 2)
# specify some map projection/options
g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showlakes = TRUE,
  lakecolor = toRGB('white')
)

p1 <- plot_ly(df, z = total.exports, text = hover, locations = code, type = 'choropleth', locationmode = 'USA-states', color = total.exports, colors = 'Purples',
marker = list(line = l), colorbar = list(title = "Millions USD"))

p2 <- plot_ly(df, z = total.exports, text = hover, locations = code, type = 'choropleth', locationmode = 'USA-states', color = total.exports, colors = 'Purples',
marker = list(line = l), colorbar = list(title = "Millions USD"))

plotly::subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 2) %>% layout(geo = g)
```

What am I misunderstanding or missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
p1 <- plot_ly(df, z = total.exports, text = hover, locations = code, type = 'choropleth', locationmode = 'USA-states', color = total.exports, colors = 'Purples',
marker = list(line = l), colorbar = list(title = "Millions USD"), geo = 'geo1')

p2 <- plot_ly(df, z = total.exports, text = hover, locations = code, type = 'choropleth', locationmode = 'USA-states', color = total.exports, colors = 'Purples',
marker = list(line = l), colorbar = list(title = "Millions USD"), geo = 'geo2')

plotly::subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 2) %>% layout(geo = g, geo2 = g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to have different scales? I have such data.

Comment: You should have added this information to your original post. I have looked and it seems possible to have multiple legends (via legendgroup) for other type plots, but I am not sure if it's possible for choropleth maps. I tried a few things but it did not work :-) It's clear what do you want for final output but you could use Rmarkdown (html doc) and have 2 maps each with their own legend

Comment: Sorry...Also, It does not produce the desired result on my computer. I am using `packageVersion('plotly') [1] ‘3.4.1’`

Comment: I am using plotly_3.4.3 (dev version)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the result of the answer above. When I try it, I get 1 map with 2 colorbars?

Comment: @LuitpoldWienerle to get to work, add `showscale = FALSE` to one of the map, and then add `layout(geo = g)` and `layout(geo2 = g)` to their respective map and then call `plotly::subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 2)` and you will get 2 maps and one colorscale.